# Create order and transaction in Credimax Mastercard Payment API

Tags: swift, payment, mastercard

I am using Credimax payment gateway API and I am trying to make card payment.
The below link shows the API endpoint which requires **Order id** and **Transaction ID**.

https://credimax.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/53/operation/Transaction%3a%20%20Pay.html?locale=en_US

I am not sure, where can I get the order id and transaction id. Going through steps in the below link does not show any way to create order. It has the specification but doesn't have proper explanation

https://credimax.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/directPayment/integrationModelDirectPayment.html

Let me know if any one has faced this issue and found any solution.

Comment: The documantation in your first link (under "Request Parameters") states for `orderid`: "*A unique identifier for this order to distinguish it from any other order you create*" so I would assume its up to you to set this value to whatever you like to identify the order, the same is true of `transactionid`.  The "More ..." link shows you how your value will be validated/what is valid.

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you for your response. I got your point but i am not sure what value should i pass. Do I have to pass any random number or I have to acquire it from some other api before payment.

Comment: Usually you would have your own orderid or similar to link the order to your own database of orders/transactions so you could set to you whatever you use to uniquely identify that order in your own system.

Comment: I tried same but nothing is working. Don't know what the issue is. For PAY api it shows "Value 'PAY' is invalid. Pay request not permitted for this merchant." and for AUTHORIZE api it shows "Value <merchantid> is invalid. No valid Merchant Acquirer Relationship available". I have sent an email to support team.

Comment: @Bhumika Have you found the solution for the Error "Value 'PAY' is invalid. Pay request not permitted for this merchant. ? If so, please help...